# How to get the value of a textbox onchange with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, events, input, knockout.js

I have the following code in knockout. The html is

```
<p id="inputField">
    What do you want to search?: 
    <input data-bind="
        textInput: searchLocation, 
        event: {focus:  focusHandler}"/>
</p>
```

The viewModel is

```
function  NeighborhoodModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.focusHandler = function(){
        console.log("focus self.searchLocation "+searchLocation());
    };

    self.searchLocation= ko.observable("");
    searchLocation = ko.observable("");
    self.locations = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.nameLocation = ko.observable(" ");
    console.log(" begin model");
    console.log("model self.searchLocation "+searchLocation());

};

ko.applyBindings(new NeighborhoodModel());
```

How can I recover the value of searchLocation?

Messages in the console are

> begin model
>
> project5.js:15 model self.searchLocation
>
> project5.js:6 focus self.searchLocation

Answer (score 1):

you've defined searchLocation twice, once on self and again immediately after that. also, you should use the `value` binding instead of textInput

see this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uete2Lsq/

```
<p id="inputField">
    What do you want to search?: 
    <input data-bind="
        value: searchLocation, 
        event: {focus:  focusHandler, blur: focusHandler}"/>
</p>
```